# What can cause auth.log to start over again?

Tags: debian, logs, rsyslog

In my Raspberry Pi running Debian, I have a simple script to output the IPs which have successfully logged into the system via SSH.

It's like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
egrep 'Accepted password|Accepted publickey' /var/log/auth.log | grep -Eo  
'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | sort -u
```

The last time I checked it, it seemed to had been logging since the first day and the list was getting pretty big.
However I checked today and was surprised to see that it only contained a few lines.
After checking /var/log/auth.log it seems it's being logging only since yesterday.

I don't recall doing anything to `rsyslogd` or anything that might have caused it to start logging again from some point.
What can cause this kind of behavior?

**EDIT:** It seems that there is a /var/log/auth.log.1 file too which contains the rest of the data.I easily modified my script, but still wonder why that happened.

Answer (score 0):

Log files are rotated & aged off. Not sure of the specifics of this log on this OS - but the tool used is "logrotate", which should have an entry for secure in /etc/logrotate.conf or /etc/logrotate.d/

Comment: Ok, I think I get it.But, it seems that the old log goes from Jan 31 (strange,since I got it on Feb 14 I think) to Apr  2,and there doesn't seem to be any rule which rotates them like that.Maybe it's according to the size (the old one is 8,9M).My [/etc/logrotate.conf:](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zK674BVu) and [/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mPFXNHJB)